# Swift: Create an optional IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, iboutlet

I'm writing a UIViewController for others to inherit from. This UIViewController has a UIScrollView in it. Currently, I create the UIScrollView like this:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: viewWidth * 2, height: viewHeight)
scrollView.delegate = self
view.addSubview(scrollView)
view.sendSubview(toBack: scrollView)
```

This works, but to make the UIViewController extensible, I want to be able to have an IBOutlet for it that people can connect their UIScrollViews to from the storyboard.

If someone connected a UIScrollView via storyboard, I'd use that scrollView. Otherwise, I'd use the code above to make it myself.

I've seen this in a library before, but can't remember the library so I can't reference how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create an outlet:

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

In `viewDidLoad`, if `scrollView` is `nil`, that means the outlet is not connected. You can check this using a simple if statement:

```
if scrollView == nil {
    scrollView = UIScrollView(...)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: viewWidth * 2, height: viewHeight)
    scrollView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    view.sendSubview(toBack: scrollView)
}
// do the things you want to do with the scroll view here.
```

Comment: Ah, I thought because of the `!` that this would crash if it was indeed nil. I guess it won't.

Comment: Yeah, turns out this was extremely trivial. I guess I thought @IBOutlet was a lot more magical than it is. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Sweeper's answer is correct, but personally, it's not necessary - not "swifty" if you will.

In the IBOutlet, just replace the `!` with `?`. That will do. Easiest. I had to test it just to make sure it's working.